# Use of preposition 'to': 'to the advantage of'

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Please explain use of *to* specific to this sentence

> An ideological deficit is to the advantage of Congress party.

Comment: I think you spelled "[ideological](http://bfy.tw/BKER)" incorrectly....

Comment: It's best to see 'to X's advantage' / 'to the advantage of X' as a fixed phrase. See [Collins sense 2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/advantage).

Comment: Thanks, @EdwinAshworth, I had been looking for a dictionary entry with the phrase.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question.  There's no context..

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiom: *to one's advantage*

> to one's benefit or gain
>
> - The error was ***to our advantage***. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20one%27s%20advantage))

The preposition ***to*** can be:

> used as a ***function word*** *to indicate the result of an action or a process, purpose, intention, tendency, or end* ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to))

Answer (score -2):

It's the preposition that usually follows the word *advantage*:

> something gives an advantage to somebody

The only difference in your example is that *to* precedes *advantage*:

> something is to the advantage of somebody